# Customize sales_order_grid ONLY IN custom module

Tags: magento2, orders, grid

I have created a custom module and admin path. I set my layout file to render `"sales_order_grid"`.  Here is the content of
**view/adminhtml/layout/custommodule_layout_index.xml**

```
<body>
    <referenceContainer name="content">
        <uiComponent name="sales_order_grid"/>
    </referenceContainer>
</body>
```

I copy paste `"sales_order_grid.xml"` to **view/ui_component** and updated some fields. But it is affecting to original **sales -> orders** grid also. (I do understand how this happens. I just don't know how to differentiate grid showing in my module from global orders grid)

And I want to remove some columns and add some filters to this grid in my module. And it should not affect to `sales_order_grid` globally. How can I achieve this?

I briefly considered copy pasting entire module_sales content and removing unnecessary files. But the original module seems little hefty to edit.

Comment: Have you found an answer for this ?

Comment: @HaidarZeineddine I couldn't find any answer. I ended up rebuilding a new grid view using original data in DB like a regular grid view.

Comment: I found a module that creates an orders grid without a complete rewrite, you can checkout the code how it's done, have a look at https://github.com/Vendic/module-extraordergrid